# Woocomerce add info after order email prouct item

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to add some labels after woocommrce order email items.

Example: We can do that on cart by using this filter.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', array( $this, 'wc_esd_show_date_cart_page' ), 10, 2 );
```

This calls the wc_esd_show_date_cart_page() function and show its data after the item name.

I want to do the same for order email items, anyone know there have some filter for it, or another way to do this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this with a differnent woocommerce hook:

```
woocommerce_order_item_meta_end ($item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text)
```

use it similarly to the cart filter above.

For a visual representation if you want the additional information somewhere else see this link:

https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-emails/

You can also always go right to the source and see all the hooks/filters/actions in woocommerce:
https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html

as an example:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'rt_order_item_meta_end', 10, 4 );
function rt_order_item_meta_end( $item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text ){
    echo '<p>cool item detail</p>';
}
```

Comment: i checked it like this
  add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', array( $this, 'wc_esd_show_email' ), 10, 3 );

public function wc_esd_show_email( $item_id, $item, $order ) {
echo 'tetsing custom text';

}

but it seems not showing, did i do anything wrong

Comment: I added an example.  Your callback needs the arguments to work.